# How to import price value to Google Sheets from a website using ImportXML function?

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use `ImportXML` on Google Sheets to import a price value from a website. Can't find the right XPATH. Please help!

I tried this line and various others and they didn't work:

```
=importxml("http://www.bizportal.co.il/mutualfunds/quote/giusimandpedionot/5124573","//div[@class='top-area-cube']//num()")
```

This is the relevant source of the page I'm trying to extract (I want the value `117.3`, under the `data-row mutual-funds"/"top-area-cube"/"num` section).

```
    <a class="add-to-portfolio " href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="portfolio.addPaper('5124573',this)" data-paper-added="0" data-user-logged="0" data-paper-id="5124573" data-name="quote-paper">
        <span class="label">הוסף לתיק אישי</span>
        <span class="icon-case2"></span>
    </a>
<h1 class="data-row">
    <span class="paper-name">תכלית MSCI WORLD TTF</span>
</h1>
    <div class="data-row mutual-funds">
        <div class="top-area-cube">
            <div class="label">מחיר פדיון</div>
            <div class="num">117.33</div>
        </div>
        <div class="top-area-cube">
            <div class="label">מחיר קנייה</div>
            <div class="num">117.33</div>
        </div>

        <span class="num percent rise"><span>0.35%</span><span class="icon icon-up"></span></span>
        <span class="num percent points-container rise"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="statistics-container">
        <ul class="row data-row statistics">
            <li><span class="label">% החודש:</span><span class="num rise">3.69%</span></li>
            <li><span class="label">% השנה:</span><span class="num rise">14.33%</span></li>
            <li><span class="label">% 3 חודשים:</span><span class="num rise">8.51%</span></li>
            <li><span class="label">% 12 חודשים:</span><span class="num rise">6.74%</span></li>
            <li><span class="label">סטיית תקן (שנה):</span><span class="num">12.11</span></li>
            <li><span class="label">שארפ (שנה):</span><span class="num">0.54</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The expected results are the value `117.33` (or any other value under this specific node) to return to the google sheets file.

The current result is `#N/A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, this site can't be scraped with any `IMPORT` formula, most likely due to anti-scraping measurements they took to promote their API